# MacBook Air no longer recognizes USB external HDDs, flash drives or SD cards

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, disk-utility, sd-card, hdd

My MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012) is no longer recognizing a USB external HDD, flash storege and even SD cards anymore.

I did nothing different than usual before I confronted this big problem. My wireless optical mouse works fine with USB. Additionally, my external HDD power light is on when connected via USB and it appears on Disk Utility, but is not seen in Finder. (Finder options are OK).

Comment: Try clicking on the "Mount" button (second button from the right) in Disk Utility (I'm assuming you're on Sierra). Does it do anything? Is it even clickable?